# Head script application/ld+json in nextjs triggers ESLint: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: next.js, eslint

I have some code similar to this. I need to add `application/ld+json` structured data, but doing it like so, triggers this ESLint error:

`ESLint: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and it refers to `scriptStringProduct` prop. Even if I only generate that code if that variable is not undefined, I get this error.
How to fix it?

```js
import Head from 'next/head';
import { IHeadTags } from '../../../utils/types';

export const Index: React.FC<IHeadTags> = (props: IHeadTags) => {
    scriptStringProduct = { __html: '' },
    isProduct = false
  } = props;

  return (
    <Head>
      {isProduct && scriptStringProduct !== undefined && (
        <script
          type='application/ld+json'
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={scriptStringProduct ?? { __html: '' }}
          key='scriptStringProduct-jsonld'
        />
      )}
    </Head>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `.eslintrc.json` file you need to turn off the rule for `next-script-for-ga`.

Example:

```js
// .eslintrc.json

{
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "next",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@next/next/no-document-import-in-page": "off",
    "@next/next/next-script-for-ga": "off" // make sure to have this rule off
  }
}
```